# Jinja variable in url_for()

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, flask, jinja2

I have a list of services accessed by links and I display them using the for statement in Jinja and the url_for() function provided by flask.

```html
    {% for service in services %}
        <a href={{ url_for(service.service_url) }}>{{service.service_name}} </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

This works fine as answered by @arsho with the services list declared in the routes file

`app.py`:

```py
services = [
    {
        "service_url": "first_page",
        "service_name": "First Page Service"
    },
    {
        "service_url": "second_page",
        "service_name": "Second Page Service"
    },
    {
        "service_url": "third_page",
        "service_name": "Third Page Service"
    }
    ]
```

In my case, I recover the list stored in a SQLite database with the following statement
`services = Services.query.all()`

The Services class is declared as following :

`models.py`

```py
class Services(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    service_name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    service_url = db.Column(db.String(32))
```

Using the flask shell I cans see whats in my database :

```
>>>service = Services.query.all()
>>>for service in services:
...   service.service_name
...
'First Page Service'
'Second Page Service'
'Third Page Service'
>>>for service in services:
...   service.service_url
...
'first_page'
'second_page'
'third_page'
```

But in this case the same line `<a href={{ url_for(service.service_url) }}>{{service.service_name}} </a>` return an internal server error.

Edit : Solved it, one of my page in the services list wasn't declared in the routes file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not to use the single quote if you are printing the values from variable in `jinja` template.

From [`flask.url_for` documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for), `url_for` accepts the method name as parameter.

Here is an example how we can use variable value in `url_for` method in the template.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/first')
def first_page():
    return 'First page'

@app.route('/second')
def second_page():
    return 'Second page'

@app.route('/third')
def third_page():
    return 'Third page'


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    services = [
    {
        "service_url": "first_page",
        "service_name": "First Page Service"
    },
    {
        "service_url": "second_page",
        "service_name": "Second Page Service"
    },
    {
        "service_url": "third_page",
        "service_name": "Third Page Service"
    }
    ]

    return render_template("url_for_example.html", services=services)
```

`url_for_example.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Dynamic URL Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    {% for service in services %}
        <li>
            <a href={{ url_for(service.service_url) }}>{{service.service_name}} </a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

Home route:

[image: home page]

After clicking on second page URL:

[image: second page]